Error in display the image by cartopy
I want to visualize the image using cartopy.
The image shows OK in the geemap.
The coding as follow:
import ee
import geemap
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

import the cartoee functionality from geemap
from geemap import cartoee
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))

roi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/Molly_HK/daymet_area")
image = crossCorr.clip(roi)

vis = {
'min': -1,
'max': 1,
'palette': ['4AAAF7',"4AE7F7", 'D3D1CD',"FFB833",'FF5B33']

}

ax = cartoee.get_map(crossCorr, region=[-30.0, 0, -180.0, 90], vis_params=vis) #[E,S,W,N]
ax = cartoee.add_colorbar(ax, vis, loc="bottom", label="Correlation", orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()

It seems to have a problem when I run the above code and get the error as follow:
HTTPError Traceback (most recent call last)
in <cell line: 21>()
19 }
20
---> 21 ax = cartoee.get_map(crossCorr, region=[-30.0, 0, -180.0, 90], vis_params=vis) #[E,S,W,N]
22 ax = cartoee.add_colorbar(ax, vis, loc="bottom", label="Correlation", orientation="horizontal")
23

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/geemap/cartoee.py in add_layer(ax, ee_object, dims, region, cmap, vis_params, **kwargs)
273 if response.status_code != 200:
274 error = eval(response.content)["error"]
--> 275 raise requests.exceptions.HTTPError(f"{error}")
276
277 image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))

HTTPError: {'code': 500, 'message': 'An internal error has occurred (request: 39097224-ab9e-4b03-a3f2-dbf977d5c506) (computation: "aa777aa76dc125ee590c2b234050d55a")', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}"


This code seems to have worked before, but now it doesn't seem to work.
